# Spring Data Mongo API Can't find a codec for interface java.util.List

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring-boot (2.0.8.RELEASE) and connecting MongoDB. While finding Documents using `mongoTemplate`, *getting this exception*; ***no issue in result***.

**Can't find a codec for interface java.util.List.**

```
Collection<String> names = getNames(); 
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("name").in(names )); 
List<Employee> employeeList = mongoTemplate.find(query, Employee.class)

@Document(collection = "employee")
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    private String _id;
    
    private String name;
    private List<String> deptNames;
    private List<Orgs> orgNames;
    private Data[] datas;
  

}
```

**Exception**

```
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecCache.getOrThrow(CodecCache.java:46)
org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:63)
org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:37)
org.bson.codecs.BsonTypeCodecMap.<init>(BsonTypeCodecMap.java:48)
org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.<init>(DocumentCodec.java:96)
org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.<init>(DocumentCodec.java:82)
org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.<init>(DocumentCodec.java:72)
org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.<init>(DocumentCodec.java:62)
org.bson.Document.toJson(Document.java:287)
org.bson.Document.toJson(Document.java:274)
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.SerializationUtils.serializeToJsonSafely(SerializationUtils.java:121)
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2256)
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2242)
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:771)
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:757)
```